# Create tar file from files in a particular directory

Tags: node.js

I need to use nodejs to create a `tar` file that isn't encompassed in a parent directory.

For example, here is the file system:

```
/tmp/mydir
/tmp/mydir/Dockerfile
/tmp/mydir/anotherfile
```

What I'm looking to do is the equivalent to this:

```
cd /tmp/mydir
tar -cvf archive.tar *
```

So, when I extract `archive.tar`, `Dockerfile` will end up in the same directory I execute the command.

I've tried `tar.gz` and a few others, but all the examples are compressing an entire directory, and not just files.

I'm doing this so I can utilize the Docker REST API to send builds.

Answer (score 6):

With a modern module [node-tar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar) you can create a .tar file like this:

```
tar.create(
    { file: 'archive.tar' },
    ['/tmp/mydir']
).then(_ => { .. tarball has been created .. })
```

The *tar.gz* module referenced in other answers is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [tar.gz](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tar.gz) module. Here is a sample code

```
var targz = require('tar.gz');
var compress = new targz().compress('/path/to/compress', '/path/to/store.tar.gz',
function(err){
         if(err)
         console.log(err);
         console.log('The compression has ended!');
});
```

### For more options, visit the [documentation page](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tar.gz).

This package is now deprecated. Check the answer provided by [@Kelin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60446188/3423104).

Comment: I saw the examples in the tar.gz module I acknowledged I tried in my original question. This isn't the answer to creating a compressed file with nodejs that contains files at the top level.

Comment: Second parameter in `new targz().compress('/path/to/compress', '/path/to/store.tar.gz',
function(err){}` is where you can specify the path

Comment: Not sure you understand the question. Try it. Your files will always be in a directory when you uncompress. I'd love to be wrong, but I could not make it happen.

Comment: The page says: "This package has been deprecated"

Answer (score 1):

Second argument to the constructor is passed on as properties to the [tar](https://github.com/npm/node-tar#tarpackproperties) module.

```
var TarGz = require('tar.gz');
var compressor = new TarGz({}, {fromBase: true});
```

This will use create the archive without top level directory.

Edit: This was undocumented in `node-tar.gz` but pull request has now been merged: https://github.com/alanhoff/node-tar.gz#tar-options

Comment: The repository is deprecated and isn't intended to be used any more.